# Ajax post not sending through all data

Tags: jquery

I'm making a ajax call using jQuery

I'm making use of the following options

```
'type'=>'POST',
'beforeSend'=>'function(){
    $("#loader").addClass("loader").html("Updating...");
    $("#add").attr("disabled","disabled");
    $("#remove").attr("disabled","disabled");
    $("#assign").attr("disabled","disabled");
    var str = "ids:";
    $("#sortable2 li").each(function(){
       if($(this).attr("id") != ""){
        str = str+$(this).attr("id")+"|";

       }
    })
    alert(str)
 }',
'data'=>'js:{group_id:$("#UserGroup_groups").val(),user_id:1}',
'success'=>'function(data,status){
  alert(data)
 }',
'complete'=>'function(){
    $("#add").removeAttr("disabled");
    $("#remove").removeAttr("disabled");
    $("#assign").removeAttr("disabled");
    $("#loader").addClass("loader").html("Update Successful...");
}'
```

My problem is I have an unordered list with `id="sortable2"`

I need to get all the id's of the list items and pass them via the ajax calls aswell

```
<ul id="sortable2">
<li id="1">...</li>
<li id="2">...</li>
<li id="3">...</li>
<li id="5">...</li>
<li id="7">...</li>
<li id="87">...</li>
</ul>
```

I tried to do this in the before function, but not sure how to pass them together with the values in the data option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to modify the scope of str so it would be visible in `'data'=>{here}`. Just declare it before calling sending function.

`'data'=>'js:{group_id:$("#UserGroup_groups").val(),user_id:1, ids: str}',`